# error C2228: left of '.size' must have class/struct/union

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector

Получаю аналогичную ошибку при каждой попытке вызвать любой метод вектора `coefficients` из приведенного ниже кода. Поясните пожалуйста, почему так происходит.

LineND.h

```
class LineND
{
private:
    vector<double> coefficients();
public:
    LineND(double a ...);
    LineND& operator=(const LineND& ln);
    void ShowFormula();
    bool LineIntersection(const LineND line) const;
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const LineND& ln);
};
```

LineND.cpp

```
#include "LineND.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>
using namespace std;
LineND::LineND(double a ...)
{
    va_list arguments;
    va_start(arguments, a);
    double argValue;
    do
    {
        argValue = va_arg(arguments, double);
        coefficients.push_back(argValue);
    }while(argValue != NULL);
    va_end(arguments);
}
LineND& LineND::operator=(const LineND& ln)
{
    coefficients.clear();
    coefficients.resize(ln.coefficients.size());
    coefficients.assign(ln.coefficients.begin(), ln.coefficients.end());
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы объявили не *приватный член класса*, а *фукнцию* под названием `coefficients`, возвращающую `std::vector<double>`.

Думаю, что предполагалось что-то следующее:

```
class LineND
{
private:
    vector<double> coefficients;
...
```

Comment: или везде в коде писать, например, не
coefficients.push_back(argValue);
а
coefficients().push_back(argValue);
хотя конечно странно это...

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Глаз замылился, как-то совсем не заметил посреди ночи. Вы конечно оказались правы.

Comment: Очень распространенная ошибка